# Изменить активити из AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(resultString != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Но `this` не работает, так как тут нет View, что мне делать? мне нужно вызвать активити и передать в него данные

Comment: Не хватает контекста. И в вашем коде и для возможности ответа. Вам надо заиметь доступ к контексту в классе-задаче. Если класс является внутренним для актвиити, то он там есть уже. Иначе - надо через конструктор передавать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ссылку в конструктор прокинуть:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void > {
    public MyActivity activity;

    public MyTask(MyActivity a) {
        this.activity = a;
    }

    //  ......

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(resultString != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и такую ссылку лучше завернуть в `WeakReference`.

Comment: `MyActivity` - это название вашей активити. Подставьте то, что надо )